# Passing php variable in url address

Tags: php, variables, header, parameter-passing

I know that I can pass a constant parameter like this:

header('Location: page.php?parameter=9999');

But how can I do it with variable? Like this:

header('Location: page.php?parameter=$variable');  ????

Comment: Can you give an example? Why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: Please read about [strings in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Use double quotes `"`

Answer (score 2):

That is correct or you can use session variables

```
<?php
sesion_start();
//set variable
$_SESSION['juanita'] = 'some value';
?>



<?php
session_start();
//get variable
$newVar = $_SESSION['juanita']; //'some value'
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Just a note, when using variables inside strings use double quotes

```
header("Location: page.php?parameter=$variable");
```

It might be better concatenate like SeanWM answer

```
$variable = 9999;
header('Location: page.php?parameter=' . $variable);
```

Comment: Thanks very much! My problem was solved with double quotes :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark some answer as solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
$variable = 9999;
header('Location: page.php?parameter=' . $variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like you are doing, just set the variable before sending any headers:

```
<?php
  $variable = "Something";
  header("Location:page.php?paramter=" . $variable);
?>
```